# Android MediaExtractor RTSP

Tags: android

I'm attempting to develop an application which downloads a live video stream via RTSP (Real Time Streaming Protocol) from a security camera.

I have successfully connected to the camera and can view the video in a `VideoView`. However, I want low level access to the data stream so have been looking into the `MediaExtractor` API.

When I set the data source to an RTSP URI I receive an `IOException` - Failed to open file. This is confusing as this same URI works correctly in `VideoView` and other media players such as VLC. I am assuming `VideoView` must be using the same `MediaExtractor` options 'under the hood'. Does `MediaExtractor` support RTSP? I was expecting my RTSP URI to be opened by the MediaExtractor. I couldn't see anywhere in the documentation where this is unsupported. If I'm missing something can you please point me in the right direction. I see there are other libraries such as FFmpeg, VLC and Live555 which are available but I was attempting to using the Android SDK if possible.

**Code (Kotlin):**

```
val extractor = MediaExtractor()
extractor.setDataSource("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov")
```

**Error:**

```
2018-12-11 15:43:23.259 21127-21127/com.crichq.myactionreplayhub E/FileSource: Failed to open file 'rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov'. (No such file or directory)
2018-12-11 15:43:23.260 21127-21127/com.crichq.myactionreplayhub D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2018-12-11 15:43:23.262 21127-21127/com.crichq.myactionreplayhub E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.crichq.myactionreplayhub, PID: 21127
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crichq.myactionreplayhub/com.crichq.myactionreplayhub.MediaExtractorActivity}: java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.
        at android.media.MediaExtractor.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaExtractor.setDataSource(MediaExtractor.java:202)
        at com.crichq.myactionreplayhub.MediaExtractorActivity.onCreate(MediaExtractorActivity.kt:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

**Andorid Version:**

compileSdkVersion 28 (Android 9.0)

**Android Test Device:**

Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (running Android 8.0.0)

Comment: did you find a working alternative for Mediaextractor?

Comment: @MohammadFneish I'm currently investigating using FFMpeg on Android with this project https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android. I am able to connect and pull video from an RTSP stream with this. One limitation however is only one FFMpeg command can be used at a time.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this library dose not support arm-v8 that is my target device. 

Answer (score 3):

MediaExtractor supports HTTP or local file only

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

public void setDataSource (String path)
Sets the data source (file-path or **http** URL) to use.

path String: the path of the file, or the **http** URL of the stream

Comment: Yeah I saw this already but I don't understand why RTSP would work fine for VideoView and then they would lock down MediaExtractor to HTTP only. There is this similar method which doesn't state mention HTTP in the documentation but this doesn't work either. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E). RTSP is mentioned in the supported media formats https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#network.